# Leave behind a substring when extracting from a regex match

Tags: python, regex

I have the following regex:

```
^https?://www.example.com(:80)?/([^/]+)/$
```

It is intended to match URLs like:

- `http://www.example.com:80/about-me/`
- `https://www.example.com/about-me/`

What I want to do when given a URL:

1. Ensure that the URL matches the regex.
2. If the URL matches the regex, extract the whole URL without `:80`.

I know how to do (1), but I need help with (2). For example, for `http://www.example.com:80/about-me/`, I want to match it with the regex first, then extract `http://www.example.com/about-me/` out of it. I want to discard `:80` during extraction. How can I do this?

I am using the `re` module from the standard library in Python 3.6.

Comment: Use 2 capturing groups `^(https?://www\.example\.com)(?::80)?(/[^/]+/)$` https://regex101.com/r/PLqYql/1 or of you know it is the right url and for any digits `(?::\d+)(/[^/]+/)$` and use a single group https://regex101.com/r/f7ARJ8/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract just the relevant groups, as in the following:

```
s = "http://www.example.com:80/about-me/"

exp = r'^(https?://www\.example\.com)(:80)?(/[^/]+/)$'

m = re.match(exp, s)
groups = m.groups()
print(groups[0] + groups[2])

# ==> http://www.example.com/about-me/
```

Note that you should escape the URL's dots using `\.`.

Answer (score 0):

You might use `urlparse` to replace the port from the url:

```
parsedUrl = urlparse('http://www.example.com:80/about-me/')
if parsedUrl.netloc == "www.example.com:80":
    stripped = parsedUrl._replace(netloc=parsedUrl.netloc.replace(":" + str(parsedUrl.port), ""))
    print(urlunparse(stripped))
```

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/fe0ABt)

Output

```
http://www.example.com/about-me/
```

---

Or use a pattern with 2 capturing groups and use those in the replacement.

If you want to match 1 or more digits instead of only 80, use `\d+` and note to escape the dot `\.`

```
^(https?://www\.example\.com)(?::80)?(/[^/]+/)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ti0cME/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/XmQRPK)

```
import re
 
regex = r"^(https?://www\.example\.com)(?::80)?(/[^/]+/)$"
s = "http://w...content-available-to-author-only...e.com:80/about-me/"
result = re.sub(regex, r"\1\2", s, 1)
print(result)
```

Output

```
http://www.example.com/about-me/
```